# Having trouble understanding some Apache .htaccess directives

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, phpbb

I have installed a forum software called phpBB. Inside it's server config file, .htaccess I see the following:

```
#
# Uncomment the statement below if you want to make use of
# HTTP authentication and it does not already work.
# This could be required if you are for example using PHP via Apache CGI.
#
# RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

And then this:

```
#
# If symbolic links are not already being followed,
# uncomment the line below.
# http://anothersysadmin.wordpress.com/2008/06/10/mod_rewrite-forbidden-403-with-apache-228/
#
# Options +FollowSymLinks
```

So for the first piece of code I looked up my `phpinfo();` and it said that my server API is `CGI/FastCGI`, PHP version 5.5.15. I belive that's what the comment means? So should I use the commented code and what does it do anyway?

Secondly I don't have `Options +FollowSymLinks` inside my root .htaccess file because I need some understanding on what it does, perhaps I'll Google it now...

Thanks in advance - any ideas?

Comment: Google, thats a good idea. Should have been the first thing you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first comment refers to **HTTP authentication**. If you are using HTTP auth, you're authenticating using an HTTP protocol mechanism, and not using forms like with PHP. That means if you *are* using HTTP auth **and** you are using something like PHP and want your PHP scripts to recognize that someone has successfully authenticated using the HTTP mechanism, then uncomment that line.

Specifically, the `RewriteRule` line takes the authorization header of the HTTP request, and stored it in an environment variable called "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION". This allows scripts (like php) to access the authorization information, and parse out a username and/or password.

The difference between HTTP auth is most easily noticed by your *browser* popping up a window asking for a username and password (perhaps for a "Realm") instead of a web form in the *content of the page you are viewing*.

The second comment is based on the files that you are serving. If the files that you serve have no symbolic links (this is sort of like a "shortcut" in windows, but in a much more basic level). If you don't know what symbolic links are, you're probably not going to care about this.

Comment: Oh, I sure don't want to have a popup like in browser ftp://, that's what you mean don't you? PErhaps I'll leave the file as it was.

Comment: @PowerUser http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication It's similar to when you go to an FTP link, except it is sorted by "Realms", and username/password gives access to a "realm" of URLs. But yes, the browser pops up a window, just like if you go to an ftp:// URL that requires a login.